# Can't see AirPlay speakers/Airport Express if ethernet is plugged in

Tags: network, wifi, airport, airplay

When my Windows laptop is connected to my network via Wi-Fi only, I can see and play to various AirPlay speakers in my house (an iHome AirPlay speaker, an Apple TV, and an Airport Express). When I plug in the ethernet cable, though, they're no longer available, even when I'm still connected to Wi-Fi. The ethernet connection goes to the same router as the Wi-Fi.

This was working normally (could see the AirPlay speakers whether or not ethernet was plugged in) until I upgraded to Windows 8. My network configuration hasn't changed.

Any ideas how to get this working properly again?